# How to continue on to the next task after agent reboot ##[error]We stopped hearing from agent xxx

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-yaml-pipelines

My yaml consists of 2 stages and stage A & b.
one of the task under stage A has to install/uninstall the drivers and needs a system reboot.
Once the self-host agent is rebooted. I want to the agent to continue to listen to next stage B. Although my agent is up after reboot and ready for listening jobs. the build that I triggered is failing with following error after sometime (approx 10-15MIN) and skipping other stages.

> **##[error]We stopped hearing from agent xxx. Verify the agent machine is running and has a healthy network connection. Anything that terminates an agent process, starves it for CPU, or blocks its network access can cause this error. For more information, see: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=846610**

**Stage A:**

```yaml
- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: install drivers
  inputs:
    verbose: false
    workingDirectory: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/$(Build.BuildId)/${{ parameters.targetfolder }}/A
    script: pnputil /add-driver xxx.inf /install
    failOnStdErr: false
    continueOnError: true
    
- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: reboot
  condition: always()
  inputs:
    verbose: true
    script: |
        echo rebooting the device...
        shutdown /r /f /t 5
```

**Stage B: **
.
.
.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPZ4Z.png)

Is there a way, I can continue to next stages for the same build after agent reboots and starts listening to jobs?

Comment: You can't reboot an agent machine while the pipeline is running. What are you trying to do with your pipeline that results in a reboot? Why do you need to install drivers that require a reboot on your pipeline agent?

Comment: The INF is for a PnP driver, during device installation Windows attempts to unload the running driver and restart the devices that use it, in order to pick up the new version of the driver.
I tried not using reboot task as well to avoid reboot ,but still install drivers task (above )fails with error  as below on task level .
Driver package added successfully.
System reboot is needed to complete install operations!
##[debug]Exit code: 3010##[debug]Leaving Invoke-VstsTool.
##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '3010'.

Comment: But why is this necessary on your agents? Are you trying to configure a server via a pipeline agent?